# How to support programmatic view dismiss on iOS 15 and earlier versions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

On iOS 14 and earlier, we  import the `presentationMode` environment variable:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

and then call `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` to dismiss the view.

This has been deprecated on iOS 15, and a new environment variable, `dismiss`, is introduced:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
```

which we can call directly using `dismiss()` to achieve the same.

I know we can do the following to call the appropriate dismiss function and support all versions:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    self.dismiss()
} else {
    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
}
```

But how do I import/define the right environment variable? As trying this doesn't work:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
} else {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
}
```

**Edit:**

Apparently using `presentationMode` to dismiss a view in a Navigation stack still works on iOS 15 Beta 4. Unless there is a TabView inside the NavigationView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                NavigationLink(destination: ChildView()) {
                    Text("View Child")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Popping...")
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("POP")
                .font(.headline)
        })
    }
}
```

`presentatinMode` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I would suggest you either target ios 15 only and use the new method or if you support older versions stick with the deprecated method. It will still work.

Comment: As I see in your question you are going have a  `@Environment` in your code! for dissing the View, right? why not just using and working with the original Value? and forget about `dismiss` and `presentationMode`

Comment: @Paulw11 I already have users on iOS 14, so targeting iOS 15 only is not an option for now. The deprecated method doesn't work on the latest iOS/Xcode Beta 4.

Comment: @swiftPunk I'm not sure I understand the suggestion. Do you mean implementing my own binding instead of relying on the provided Environment variables?

Comment: @mota: yes. that would be safer way also you have clear code for you in future to use your code or refactoring it. If you see the fact using dismiss and the older code gave more complexly situation for SwiftUI to find which Binding you are mentioning! It is asking for problem.

Comment: @Paulw11 My apologies. It does work indeed. I have a TabView inside the nav view and in that case it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @swiftPunk Makes sense. I might resort to implementing my own solution at the end!

Comment: @mota: It seems cool to just using dismiss and not mentioning the real Binding! but you gave lots of work to SwiftUI or your project to find out what are u mentioning.

Comment: I just tried your code and this seems to be working fine on the latest Xcode (Version 13.0 (13A233)), targeting iOS 14 and above.

Comment: @vauxhall thanks for the update. They might have fixed it later!

Answer (score 10):

To support dismiss and iOS 14 add this extension to your EnvironmentValues

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dismiss: () -> Void {
        { presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't like "just use deprecated stuff cause it works" approach I was looking for an answer on this matter as well.

The best solution I could come up so far which doesn't require too much code change as well and uses `DismissAction` when available is this:

```
extension EnvironmentValues {
    // this can be used as: @Environment(\.dismissable) var myDismiss
    // in any swiftui view and it will not complain about ios versions 
    var dismissable: () -> Void {
        return dismissAction
    }
    

    // this function abstracts the availability check so you can
    // avoid the conflicting return types and any other headache
    private func dismissAction() {
        if #available(iOS 15, *) {
            dismiss()
        } else {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

just in case anyone's unclear with the usage of this new environment value here is an example (some parts, like navigation or presenting are ommited):

```
// view inside navigation/sheet
struct SomeInnerView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissable) var myDismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("dismiss me way 1") { myDismiss() } // tapping will result in a dismissing of this view
            Button("dismiss me way 2", action: myDismiss) // p.s this was not directly possible with DismissAction
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this apple not yet fix the bug in SwiftUI. So far I am following the below approach it will work for me all the versions. Might be it will
helpful for your situation

```
//presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
   
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how you'd use this in SwiftUI. Can you explain more please?

Comment: thanks ! I had a scroll view in my popover and for iOS 16 @Environment(\.dismiss) didn't work, nor does @Binding var showPopover = false. This dismisses my popover perfect

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
```

and [here](https://scottm.medium.com/dismissing-swiftui-model-views-in-ios-15-and-macos-12-50ac174ec901) is the source.